# Another font for italic, and Open Features

Tags: fonts, xetex, babel, microtype, opentype

**Xelatex**

I can set special font for italics so

```
\setmainfont[ItalicFont={Ropa Mix PTT}]{Theano Old Style}
```

I can set Open features, or Letter spacing so:

```
\newfontfamily{\notefnt}{Slopes}[LetterSpace=8.0]
\setsansfont[StylisticSet=4]{Ropa Mix PTT}
```

How can I set Italics with Letterspasing or StylistiSet?

```
\setmainfont[ItalicFont={Ropa Mix PTT, StylisticSet=4}]{Theano Old Style} % Error
% OR
\setmainfont[ItalicFont={Slopes, LetterSpace=8.0}]{Theano Old Style} % Also error
```

My preambule

```
\documentclass[draft, twoside, 11pt, openright]{extbook}
\usepackage[a5paper, outer=20mm,inner=15mm,top=20mm,bottom=20mm,footskip=1.5em,headsep=4pt,headheight=1em]{geometry}
% \usepackage[a5paper, outer=36mm,inner=15mm,top=20mm,bottom=28mm,footskip=1.5em,headsep=4pt,headheight=1em]{geometry}
\usepackage[russian,ukrainian]{babel}    %% загружает пакет многоязыковой вёрстки
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{titlesec,titletoc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usepackage{metalogo}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage[final]{microtype}
\usepackage{verse}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
```

Comment: Does section III.3 of the `fontspec` manual help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `BoldFeatures=`, `ItalicFeatures=`, etc.  See chapter 3 of [the `fontspec` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/unicodetex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.pdf) for the full details.

```
\setmainfont{Theano Old Style}[
  ItalicFont={Ropa Mix PTT},
  ItalicFeatures={StylisticSet=4} ]
```

There is one special case, in section 4.3 of the manual.  If you are defining a custom series and shape, you do use a different syntax similar to the one you guessed.  For example, to set a custom semibold slanted small caps face:

```
\defaultfontfeatures[SomeFont]{
  FontFace = {sb}{scsl}{ Font = {*-SemiboldOblique}, Letters=SmallCaps }
}
```